# El subjuntivo en la frase relativa

Tags: subjuntivo

Me cuesta mucho entender la razón por la que se utiliza el subjuntivo en la siguiente frase:

> *Y será precisamente usted, señor, quien **se encargue** de investigar este caso.*

¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo en la oración relativa si sabemos que se trata de una CIERTA persona (el antecedente es existente) y no expresamos ni duda ni improbabilidad?

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El modo subjuntivo, además de proponer situaciones hipotéticas también expresa deseo. La frase se puede reescribir como:

> Deseo que usted se encargue de investigar este caso.

Sin embargo, el ejemplo sobre el cuál haces la pregunta expresa un deseo que, dependiendo del rango de quien lo dice, es más bien una orden equivalente a:

> Señor, encárguese de investigar este caso.

La frase al ser dicha  por un mayor en la forma que propones, pese al hecho de que esté expresada en modo subjuntivo y lleva un matiz de deseo, no demerita su calidad de orden. Un ejemplo más directo sería:

> Quiero que se encargue de la investigación.

Si lo dice el jefe o una persona de alto rango, el deseo implica una orden. Si lo dice un par o un subalterno, es solo un deseo.

---

Otras opciones posibles con significados variables son:

> Me conformo, señor, si se encarga de investigar este caso.
>
> Si tuviera la capacidad necesaria, señor, usted sería quien se encargase de investigar este caso.

También podemos usar el modo indicativo:

> Usted, señor, se encargará de investigar este caso.

Answer (score 2):

No estoy muy seguro si con esta observación ayudaré a resolver tu duda o complicarla más.  En cualquier caso:

> De todos, usted será el que se encargue.

A mi entender, aquí el subjuntivo especifica dentro de un grupo quién es el que se *encargará*.  El subjuntivo es usado aquí también como imperativo.

Me gustaría poder ayudarte más, pero no creo haber entendido muy bien tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Otra interpretación de la frase sería un tono irónico, además del imperativo. En todo caso, sólo el contexto de la frase permitiría decidir la intención del hablante. Por lo demás, la construcción es correcta en Castellano.